# Unable to connect MS SQL server via Java Class

Tags: java, netbeans, mssql-jdbc

I am getting error when I try to connect database

**Error:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection cannot be cast to

    Ptakip.Connection**

- Ptakip is my Package
- Connection is my Class

  Here is the Connection Class Code ;

  ```
   import java.sql.*;

  public class Connection {
  private Connection cn;

  public Connection connector( )
  {


  try {

      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
       Connection  cn =  (Connection)     
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MyServer:     
    1433;databaseName=TEST;user=Glassfish;password=pass;");

      System.out.println("connected");
    }

     catch(Exception ex) {

     System.out.println("Error:" +  ex.getMessage());
     System.out.println(cn);

    }
      return cn;

     }

   }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your class has the same name as the class in the  package java.sql that's why u have this conflict ,juste try to change the name to Connexion ,it should work

Comment: Or just cast with the full class Name: `Connection  cn =  (java.sql.Connection)     
  DriverManager.getConnection(...)`

Comment: Thanks Pablo , it was my mistake which I did , I am connected now. Thanks very Much

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a connection like this. it may help you

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"; 
String dbName = "demo” 
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
String userName = "root"; 
String password = "mypasswd"; 
try { 
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
 conn.close(); 
}catch (Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: Thansk Saurab your way is ok ,  my mistake was using the same class names